# Amein and Food in One's Mouth

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, amen

Where in *halachah* does it say that one shouldn't answer *amein* to someone else's *berachah*, if they have food in their mouth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This halacha is mentioned in *Kol Bo* ([§24](http://books.google.com/books?id=afY9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT46#v=onepage&q&f=false)). The *Kol Bo* mentions two possible reasons<sup>1</sup> for why someone should not answer *amein* with food in his mouth:

- Just as a person should not recite a *b'racha* with food in his mouth,<sup>2</sup> he should not answer *amein* to a *b'racha* if food is in his mouth.
- It is dangerous to talk with food in one's mouth.

The *Kol Bo* prefers the second reason, and he reads the *Y'rushalmi* ([*B'rachos* 6:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1106.htm)) as implying that one should not answer *amein* with food in his mouth due to danger.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The *Kol Bo* mentions another interpretation of the *Y'rushalmi* (quoted in fn. 3 below) that a person who is eating will not be *yotzei* on another person's *b'racha* because he will be concentrating on eating rather than on the *b'racha*.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Based on the *Y'rushalmi* ([*B'rachos* 6:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1106.htm)): רבי יצחק בר מרי קומי רבי יוסי ב"ר אבון בשם רבי יוחנן אפילו אוכלין פולטן דכתיב [ימלא פי תהילתך כל היום תפארתך](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2671.htm#8)</sub>

<sup>3</sup> <sub>שאלו את בן זומא מפני מה בא להן יין בתוך המזון כל אחד ואחד מברך לעצמו אמר להן מפני שאין בית הבליעה פנוי א"ר מנא הדא אמרה אהן דעטיש גו מיכלא אסור למימר ייס בגין סכנתא דנפשא</sub>

Comment: Does the mishnah berurah talk about this?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Not as far as I recall, but the *Mishna B'rura* does explain the problem with reciting blessings with food in one's mouth ([172:7](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%91)). One *acharon* who indicates it is a problem to answer *amein* with food in one's mouth is the מטה משה (*Amud HaAvoda* §299). I also found another *rishon* who mentions this ([*Ohel Mo'eid*, *Sha'ar B'rachos* 6:2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7602&st=&pgnum=249)).

Comment: I mean, does the mishnah berurah say that one shouldn't answer amein to someone else's berachah, if they have food in their mouth?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I don't think so, but aside from the requirement of ימלא פי תהילתך mentioned by the *Mishna B'rura* in my above comment (172:7), see the *Shulchan Aruch* ([OC 170:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)) who explains that saying even a single word while eating is prohibited due to danger (see also *Mishna B'rura* 170:1,2 for clarification).

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah - If the other person is making a bircat hanehin, esp. on the food that he's eating, isn't swallowing the food in a sense, the "completion" of the bracha that he made on the food? I.e. - it goes along with the concept that one should not answer "Amen" until the bracha has been completed?

Comment: Note, however that if there is a fear of danger in saying amen while eating, one shouldnt speak at all while eating! Clearly this is not the generally accepted view. Shaarei Teshuva OH 170:1 quotes the Elya Rabba citing the Perisha that this is not a concern today (because we are not eating reclining).