# Halacha of saying bracha while someone else has food in their mouth

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, eating, derech-eretz-manners

I have heard it is forbidden to recite a bracha (loudly) when someone nearby has food in their mouth. I heard the reason is because they might choke when trying to say amen. I would also like to know if the reason might be that it makes it difficult/impossible for them to say amen and that might be another halachic issue.

Where is this halacha? How strict is this halacha? I don't see many people follow it, plus it is hard to follow when at a kiddush etc, because there are many people there and at any given moment there is almost certainly someone within earshot who has food in their mouth.

Comment: You're probably thinking of https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%97

Comment: Just say it quietly?

Comment: @Heshy thanks, see edit as I am not focussing on that. Thanks DoubleAA, I'll check it out.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43505